# $(0,1]$ is connected in relative topology. Different proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

The interval $X=(0,1]$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t the relative topology.

I am trying to show that $\emptyset, X$ are the only subsets which are both open and closed (I have seen the direct proof of connectedness of (0,1]).

Let $A\subset X$ be open and closed and let $A \neq \emptyset$. So $\exists a\in A$, how to show that $A$ has to contain $[a,1]$?

$A$ is open $A=X \cap I$ where $I$ is some open interval, hence $\exists \delta_1 >0$ s.t. $(a-\delta_1, a+\delta_1) \subset A$. Consider $a+\delta_1$, since $A^c$ is open then $a+\delta_1 \in A$, so $\exists \delta_2>0$ s.t. $a+\delta_1+\delta_2 \in A$.

Like this we get a series and clearly $a+\sum_{i=1}^\infty \delta_i =:a+s \in A$. It can happen that $a+s <1$ then we repeat the process for $a+s$. But how to prove that such a process terminates in the sense that we reach $1$? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can't conclude that $A=X\cap I$ for some open interval $I$; all you know is that $A=X\cap U$ for some open *set* (possibly not an interval) $U$. This isn't really a problem, though.

Actually, things are simpler than they seem. Look at step two of your process:

- You have $a\in A$.
- So $(a, a+\delta)\subseteq A$ - let $\delta$ be the largest possible so that this is true.
- Now suppose $a+\delta\not\in A$. Then since $A$ is closed, there is some small $\epsilon>0$ such that $(a+\delta-\epsilon, a+\delta)\subseteq X\setminus A$.
- But then $a+\delta-{\epsilon\over 2}$ is both in and out of $A$! Contradiction. So $[a, 1]\subseteq A$.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about using compactness but couldn't get an open cover for $[a,1]$. How can we get an infinite cover for $[a,1]$?

Comment: @user16015 Actually, it's easier than that - see my edit.